# Ошибка, вызывающая многократное открытие окна

Tags: java, awt

Программирую небольшую программу в Netbeans. Требуется из меню открыть новое окно, в котором будут проводиться вычисления. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при открытии нового фрейма он открывается много раз, после чего программа вылетает. Привожу текст трех классов (в меню обрабатываются пока только первые три кнопки):

```
package temnikovav_321_pe_cw;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public MainJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    openTask = new javax.swing.JButton();
    openTheory = new javax.swing.JButton();
    openCiclingCalc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    BidimensArray = new javax.swing.JButton();
    StringsAndArrays = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Classes = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mainPanel.setName(""); // NOI18N

    openTask.setText("Открыть задание");
    openTask.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openTaskActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    openTheory.setText("Открыть теоретическую часть");
    openTheory.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openTheoryActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    openCiclingCalc.setText("Циклические вычислительные процессы");
    openCiclingCalc.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openCiclingCalcActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    BidimensArray.setText("Двумерные массивы");

    StringsAndArrays.setText("Строки и файлs");

    Classes.setText("Классы");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(Classes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(StringsAndArrays, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(BidimensArray, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(openTheory, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(openTask, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(openCiclingCalc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(openTask)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(openTheory)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(openCiclingCalc)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(BidimensArray)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(StringsAndArrays)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(Classes)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void openTaskActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    TaskForm tf;
    tf = new TaskForm();
}

private void openTheoryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:    
    File theory;
    theory = new File("res/Temnikov_321_Program_Engineering");
    Desktop desktop = null;
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    }
    try {
        desktop.open(theory);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}

private void openCiclingCalcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    CiclingCalc cc = new CiclingCalc();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton BidimensArray;
private javax.swing.JButton Classes;
private javax.swing.JButton StringsAndArrays;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton openCiclingCalc;
private javax.swing.JButton openTask;
private javax.swing.JButton openTheory;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Второй класс:

```
package temnikovav_321_pe_cw;

public class TaskForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public TaskForm() {
    initComponents();
    ShowTaskArea();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    TaskText = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    TaskText.setColumns(20);
    TaskText.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(TaskText);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 251, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 */
private void ShowTaskArea(){
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TaskForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
    String s;
    s = "1. Циклические вычислительные процессы \n";

    TaskText.setText(s);
    TaskText.setEditable(false);

}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextArea TaskText;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Третий класс:

```
package temnikovav_321_pe_cw;

import javax.swing.JTable;

public class CiclingCalc extends javax.swing.JFrame {
final String[] colNames = {"№ п/п", "x", "F"};//название колонок таблицы

public CiclingCalc() {
    initComponents();

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CiclingCalc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CiclingCalc().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    CCJPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FieldA = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FieldB = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FieldC = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FieldXn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FieldXk = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FieldDx = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    ResultTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    FieldDescription = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("A:");

    FieldA.setToolTipText("");

    jLabel2.setText("Циклические вычисления");

    jLabel3.setText("B:");

    jLabel4.setText("C:");

    FieldC.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            FieldCActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel5.setText("Начало диапазона:");

    jLabel6.setText("Конец диапазона:");

    FieldXk.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            FieldXkActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel7.setText("шаг:");

    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(ResultTable);

    jButton1.setText("Рассчитать");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    FieldDescription.setText("jTextField3");
    FieldDescription.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));
    FieldDescription.setEnabled(false);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout CCJPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(CCJPanel);
    CCJPanel.setLayout(CCJPanelLayout);
    CCJPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED))
                                        .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                            .addGap(5, 5, 5)))
                                    .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(FieldB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(FieldC))
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(FieldA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(FieldXn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(FieldXk)
                                .addComponent(FieldDx)))
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addComponent(FieldDescription, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    CCJPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(FieldA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(FieldXn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(FieldB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(FieldXk, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(CCJPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(FieldC, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addComponent(FieldDx, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(FieldDescription, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 156, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(CCJPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(CCJPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    CCJPanel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    CCJPanel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать заменить

```
/* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CiclingCalc().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

На

```
/
    * Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CiclingCalc.this.setVisible(true);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек! Всё сработало. Я уж начинал искать, вдруг где-то случайно рекурсию прописал.